# Permutation question for evidence at a mock trial

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability that one letter and one number appear on a license plate (in any order) if the plate consists of six elements that can be a letter, a number, and can repeat?  I am a law student so I really do not possess the skills to approach this problem.  This is for a mock trial where an eyewitness remembers seeing a "K" and an "8" on a license plate.  This is in Florida where plates have $6$ alpha numeric characters and I would like to know how many plates have those characters out of the set of all possible plates.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

The only work I have done on this problem is figuring out how many plates are possible as a permutation $36^6 = 2,176,782,336$.

No idea how to approach the other half of the problem.

Comment: Please change the silly header.  After that, please show your efforts towards the solution.

Comment: I edited the title because the original was mere click-bait unrelated to the post.  @Brandon, please don't use those antics again on this site.  You'll annoy people to no end.  Secondly, this site is not a "do my work for me" service.  If you want help on a question, come here prepared to add context to your question, e.g., what you yourself think and/or any workings from your attempt(s), even if it ends up wrong, or you get stuck half-way through.  The surest way to earn downvotes and close votes is by posting a bare statement of an exercise, copied and pasted from a text/pdf/ etc.

Comment: Now, with this exercise you've copied for us to do for you, you can reverse course and edit your post to include what you've tried, not just in claims, but showing us what you've tried, correct or not, or up to when you get stuck.  In that case, please ask specifically about what you don't understand.

Comment: @user243301  It "was mere click-bait unrelated to the post". Mathematics is not done according to what "seems right, feels right, by allegory, nor by figurative language."  An allegory or figurative language might belong on Literature.SE, or ELU.SE, or any number of interpretive se sites.  Doesn't belong here.

Comment: I've deleted my comment (for the recipient, that was not you) @amWhy

Comment: Sorry about the breach of ettiquette.  I am actually a law student trying to prepare for a mock trial (hence the click bait).  I would include any work if I actually had any idea how to do it.  If anyone is willing to help with this I would greatly appreciate it, but I completely understand if you do not want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of plates that don't have a K is $35^6$. The nummber that don't have an 8 is also $35^6$. The number that have neither a K nor an 8 is $34^6$. So the number that do have at least one K and at least one 8 is $$36^6-2\times35^6+34^6$$

Comment: Thanks, that means less than 3% of all possible plate combinations.  Combine that  with the fact that even the car in question is a late model green American car...you may have just won me my case!